# AWS Transfer Family using FTPS and MultiPart Upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-transfer-family

Is it possible to use the MultiPart upload feature for S3 when AWS Transfer Family is configured with SFTP? While there's a workaround to split and upload each file segment to S3, this results In separate chunks. I need the file to be reassembled in S3.

My understanding is if the user can access the S3 objects only via SFTP, and not possible to use AWS SDK then it is not possible to use this feature!